# Laplace's equation on Lorentzian manifold

Tags: harmonic-functions, wave-equation, general-relativity, hyperbolic-equations, partial-differential-equations

In general relativity one wants to find "harmonic" functions $u$ on (a neighborhood $U$ in) a Lorentzian manifold $(M, g)$. In arbitrary coordinates $\{x^\mu\}$ the equation $\Delta_g u =  0$ reads 
$$
g^{\mu\nu}(\partial_{\mu\nu}u - \Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}\partial_\alpha u) = 0. \tag{$1$}
$$
My question is how exactly to show existence/uniqueness of solutions via results for second order linear equations (equation (1) is such an equation). If $g$ were Riemannian, we could apply linear elliptic theory to this equation. However, even then, after specifying boundary conditions, I am not sure if we are guaranteed existence, since Lax-Milgram and the Fredholm alternative only give existence under certain conditions on the coercivity of the associated bilinear form.

However, for the Lorentzian metric, we want to get this into a hyperbolic form $\partial_{tt} u + L'u = 0$, where $L'$ is an elliptic operator. However, a priori (1) involves all sorts of mixed partials, and so I am unsure how to get (1) into this form, or if this is even the right approach.

For context: this is on the road to showing local existence of wave coordinates on a Lorentzian manifold. I would be interested in any resources on this topic. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't have the time to type it right now, but look at Lemma 2 in page 13 of Tilla Weinstein's *Introduction to Lorentz Surfaces*. It is essentially taking a local frame of lightlike vectors, performing a suitable change of basis and applying Frobenius' theorem, it doesn't require any heavy functional analysis or facts about differential operators in general. (of course, her result is for surfaces but you might be able to adapt it somehow)

Comment: That's the wave equation. Look Friedlander, [The wave equation on curved space-time](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Equation-Space-Time-Cambridge-Monographs-Mathematical/dp/0521136369).